# How to run multi Cron Expression in one command to schedule jobs in Jira

Tags: cron, jira

I'm trying to run multi Cron Expression in one command to schedule jobs in Jira, such as

```
0 36 0 18 10 ? 2023
0 37 0 18 10 ? 2023 
0 38 0 18 10 ? 2023
0 10 23 18 10 ? 2023
```

But the automation will only run the first Cron Expression and ignore the rest. Is there anyway to combine them together? something like

```
0 36 0 18 10 ? 2023, 0 37 0 18 10 ? 2023,  0 38 0 18 10 ? 2023, 0 10 23 18 10 ? 2023,
```

But in this way I will receive syntax error from it.

So how can I run multi Cron Expression in one command, as I only need the trigger once in certain date not in every certain time range. Only need it once in a year.

```
0 36 0 18 10 ? 2023, 0 37 0 18 10 ? 2023,  0 38 0 18 10 ? 2023, 0 10 23 18 10 ? 2023,
```

This is what I tried: , : and | . But in this way I will receive syntax error from it.